# Pass jQuery datepicker values to second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a simple jQuery datepicker form (code below) that I'm trying to pass those values to my next page. It's for a booking form and I have two steps in the process. I want to be able to take the dates selected from the first step to the second step on another page. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="booking-wrap-horz cf">  <div class="bookingform cf">    
<form class="b-form" action="nextpage.html" id="myform" method="post" target="_blank">              
            <div class="arrival group">
                    <input type="text" name="A" id="arrive" class="datepicker required" placeholder="ARRIVE"></div>
                <div class="departure group">
                    <input type="text" name="D" id="depart" class="datepicker required" placeholder="DEPART">
                </div>

                <div class="adults group">
                    <select name="Ad" id="adults" class="dk">
                        <option selected disabled>adults</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="bookbtn group">
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="booksub">Book Now</button>
                </div>
            </form>

</div></div>
```

Comment: how is the transition taking place as in from one page to another, when do we jump -> the trigger.

Comment: After they add the arrival date and the departure date plus the number of adults they submit the information. Before the form sent the values to an offsite page, but I'm trying to pass this form data to a second page on my website. The form on the second page has the same datepicker form as above (same ID and name) but adds a few more selections the user has to select.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with jquery or datepicker. It's just passing values from one page to another. Use sessionStorage or query string parameters or something server side depending on what your back end is.